# how to have 2 messsage box with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar, messagebox, taskmanager

i have been trying to make a kind of reminder that pop your next task but i also wanted another indicator that tells the next task the issue is when the next task pop up is opened the other one cant open

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

routine_schedule = [
    (8, 0, "Wake up and hydrate"),
    (8, 15, "Mindfulness or meditation"),
    (8, 30, "Morning exercise"),
    (9, 0, "Healthy breakfast"),
    (9, 30, "Start coding session"),
    (10, 55, "Pomodoro break - Stretch and hydrate"),
    (11, 0, "Back to coding"),
    (12, 30, "Lunch break"),
    (13, 30, "Outdoor time"),
    (14, 0, "Continue coding"),
    (15, 25, "Pomodoro break - Creative activity"),
    (15, 30, "Coding session"),
    (17, 0, "Evening workout/activity"),
    (18, 0, "Healthy dinner"),
    (19, 0, "Relaxation time"),
    (20, 0, "Digital detox"),
    (21, 0, "Prepare for sleep"),
]

def notify_task(task):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw() 
    messagebox.showinfo("Task Reminder", f"It's time to: {task}")
    root.destroy()

def get_next_task():
    current_time = time.localtime()
    for schedule_hour, schedule_minute, schedule_task in routine_schedule:
        if (current_time.tm_hour < schedule_hour) or (current_time.tm_hour == schedule_hour and current_time.tm_min < schedule_minute):
            return schedule_hour, schedule_minute, schedule_task
    return None

def display_next_task():
    next_task = get_next_task()
    if next_task:
        next_hour, next_minute, next_task_description = next_task
        next_task_text = f"Next task: {next_task_description}\nTime: {next_hour:02d}:{next_minute:02d}"
        root1 = tk.Tk()
        root1.withdraw()
        messagebox.showinfo("Next Task", next_task_text)
        root1.destroy()

# Main routine loop
while True:
    current_time = time.localtime()
    display_next_task()
    for schedule_hour, schedule_minute, schedule_task in routine_schedule:
        if current_time.tm_hour == schedule_hour and current_time.tm_min == schedule_minute:
            notify_task(schedule_task)
    
    time.sleep(0)
```

i tryied everything i think

Comment: the time.sleep(0) was because it was set to a minute but for testing purpose i changed it to 0

Comment: Don't use a messagebox. You can create as many instances of a `Toplevel` that you want.

Comment: Replace `root1 = tk.Tk()` with `root1 = tk.Toplevel(`).

Comment: Why are you destroying `root.destroy()` and `root1.destroy()`. And where is `root.mainloop()`?

Comment: You should only be creating one `root` instance of `tk.Tk()`, and you shouldn't be `destroy`ing it until you are ready to exit the application. And you should avoid using `sleep` at all in a tkinter app as it will hang the GUI while sleeping. @BryanOakley is right - minimize your `root` window and instantiate however many `Toplevel` windows you need as children of `root`.